# cvs2git covert cvs to git and push multiple branches gets: error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, github, cvs, cvs2svn, cvs2git

I use cvs2git to convert a cvs repo to git. This project/repo has multiple branches and tags. Anyway I was able to (didn't get any error msg) convert this cvs repo to git. But when I push the git project to github I am getting this error. I think it might be I am push it to Master, but I have multiple branches. If that's the case, how can I push multiple branches to github? Thanks!

Here are the commands I ran:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/mygithub/MyProject.git
git push -u origin master

Complete Error:
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mygithub/MyProject.git'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a branch named master in your local repository?  `git branch` will show you your local branches.

It might be that you want to do `git push --mirror`

> --mirror Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/,
>   refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote repository.
>   Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally
>   updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs
>   will be removed from the remote end. This is the default if the
>   configuration option remote..mirror is set.

Comment: Just ran "git show-branch" and got "No revs to be shown." I guess I have some problem with "git fast-import". Thanks!